# Remote Procedure Call and MIDL: How to implement function with [out] attribute?

Tags: c++, server, client, rpc, midl

I'm writing server and client using Interface Definition Language and Remote Procedure Call in C++. I can send data from client to server with [in] attribute. Now I want server to send data back to client. But I failed receiving correct data.

I define the function in .idl interface as below:

```
[
    //uuid and verison define here
]

interface utility{
    void sendData([in] int numIn, [out] int *numOut);
}
```

The [MIDL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367136(v=vs.85).aspx) document says that

> An [out]-only parameter is assumed to be undefined when the remote procedure is called and memory for the object is allocated by the server.

So in client.cpp, I instantiate the variable and call the funciton.

```
RpcTryExcept{
    int *num;
    sendData(hBinding, 123, num);
}
```

In server.cpp,

```
void sendData(handle_t IDL_handle, int numIn, int *numOut){
    numOut = new int[3];
    numOut[0] = 1;
    numOut[1] = 2;
    numOut[2] = 3;     
}
```

I printed the int array in client, and get 3 random numbers. I also tried to define the size in client first. 
`int *num = new int[3]`. This time it can pass the value of numOut[0] to client, but the other indexes are all messed up. I tried char array as well but no good. Maybe I misunderstanding something. Can anyone give me some ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code

```
void sendData(handle_t IDL_handle, int numIn, int *numOut){
    numOut = new int[3];
    numOut[0] = 1;
    numOut[1] = 2;
    numOut[2] = 3;     
}
```

only changes the value copy of the pointer parameter and leaves you with a memory leak.

I'd suspect an implementation should rather look like

```
void sendData(handle_t IDL_handle, int numIn, int *numOut){
    *numOut = 42;
}
```

To return an array with an `[out]` parameter the signature would rather look like

```
void sendData(handle_t IDL_handle, int numIn, int **numOut);
```

Check your IDL definitions again.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Now I'm a bit confusing. When server send an int array or float array (I read file into float array) to client, it works with either float * or float[] in IDL. But when client send data to server, it shows different behavior. I will try to figure it out.